# How do I make different buttons print in the same place?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I am creating a simple website for learning purposes with multiple buttons. At the moment, the buttons (HTML) print values on different places but I want it to print in the same place. That is:

You click button 1, value Y prints on X.
You click button 2, value Y disappears and value Z prints on X.
Etc.

I tried different approaches but can't get it to work.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="sexF()">sex</button><br><br>
                <h1><span id="sex"></span></h1><br><br>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="relationshipF()">relationship</button><br><br>
                <h1><span id="relationship"></span></h1><br><br>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="randomF()">random</button><br><br>
                <h1><span id="random"></span></h1><br><br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my JS code:

```
var sex = ["(array1)"]
        
var relationship = ["(array2)"]
        
var random = ["(array3)"]

function sexF() {
    var sexQuestion = sex[Math.floor(Math.random() * sex.length)];
    document.getElementById("sex").innerHTML = sexQuestion;
}

function relationshipF() {
    var relationshipQuestion = relationship[Math.floor(Math.random() * relationship.length)];
    document.getElementById("relationship").innerHTML = relationshipQuestion;
}

function randomF() {
    var randomQuestion = random[Math.floor(Math.random() * random.length)];
    document.getElementById("random").innerHTML = randomQuestion;
}
```

Comment: I don't see the problem. Remove the 3 spans, add a new element for the output, and have all three functions write to that.

Comment: i don't understand your problem please ask your question with another way or better

Answer (score 0):

```js
var sex = ["(array1)"]
        
var relationship = ["(array2)"]
        
var random = ["(array3)"]

function sexF() {
    var sexQuestion = sex[Math.floor(Math.random() * sex.length)];
    document.getElementById("sex").innerHTML = sexQuestion;
    document.getElementById("div1").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("div2").style.display="block";
}

function relationshipF() {
    var relationshipQuestion = relationship[Math.floor(Math.random() * relationship.length)];
    document.getElementById("relationship").innerHTML = relationshipQuestion;
    document.getElementById("div2").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("div3").style.display="block";
}

function randomF() {
    var randomQuestion = random[Math.floor(Math.random() * random.length)];
    document.getElementById("random").innerHTML = randomQuestion;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4" id="div1">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="sexF()">sex</button><br><br>
                <h1><span id="sex"></span></h1><br><br>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4"  style="display:none" id="div2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="relationshipF()">relationship</button><br><br>
                <h1><span id="relationship"></span></h1><br><br>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4"  style="display:none" id="div3">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="randomF()">random</button><br><br>
                <h1><span id="random"></span></h1><br><br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You have to try this code this is simple code hide and show that particular division.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code quite a bit ("DRY" = don't repeat yourself!):

```js
const sex = ["male","female","other"],
      relationship = ["acquaintance","friend","lover","spouse"],
      random = ["q1","q2","q3"];

function ask(topic) {
  document.getElementById("question").innerHTML =
   topic[Math.floor(Math.random() * topic.length)];
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="ask(sex)">sex</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="ask(relationship)">relationship</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="ask(random)">random</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><br><br>
<h1><span id="question"></span></h1>
```

Or, in an even more reduced form it could look like this:

```js
const topics={
  sex:["male","female","other"],
  relationship:["acquaintance","friend","lover","spouse"],
  random:["q1","q2","q3"] };

document.querySelector(".container").onclick=ev=>{
  if (ev.target.tagName=="BUTTON") {
   let t=topics[ev.target.innerText];
   document.getElementById("question").innerHTML =
     t[Math.floor(Math.random() * t.length)];
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">sex</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">relationship</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">random</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><br><br>
<h1><span id="question"></span></h1>
```